# K Framework produces an error in the OCaml backend

Tags: ocaml, formal-verification, formal-methods, formal-semantics, kframework

I am using the [K semantics Framework](http://www.kframework.org/index.php/Main_Page) and running tutorials 
this is my TEST1.k :

```
module TEST1-SYNTAX 
import DOMAINS


syntax Fun ::= "add(" Pgm "," Pgm ")"        [strict]
syntax Pgm ::= Int 
            | Fun

endmodule

module TEST1
import TEST1-SYNTAX

    rule add( I1:Int , I2:Int) => I1 +Int I2

    configuration <T  color="blue">
                <k color ="red"> $PGM:Pgm </k> 


    </T>
endmodule
```

but I get this error when run command Kompile Test1.k:

```
File "realdef.ml", line 2151, characters 331-338:
Error: This variant expression is expected to have type bool
   The constructor KApply1 does not belong to type bool
 [Error] Critical: ocamlopt returned nonzero exit code: 2
Examine output to see errors.
```

Comment: i know that problem is in [strict]. because when i remove that everything is ok but I wanted

Comment: it looks like a bug in the ocaml-backend (even if your input is wrong, this is not a sane way to report it), so please submit a bug report to the upstream: https://github.com/kframework/k/issues